# Right way to change HTML element when the element is saved as a constant (Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable)

Tags: javascript, html, constants

Im trying to change the documents html text (value).
It is working but it also gives this error Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
Is there another way to replace the value?

```
//The element
let items = 1
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
itemCountSpan.innerHTML = items
```

Comment: use `var` instead of `const`

Answer (score 0):

A constant is a value that cannot be altered by the program during normal execution. It cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared. In JavaScript, constants are declared using the const keyword.
[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_const_assignment). So, if you want to avoid that error use let